# C Multithreaded program that uses pthreads to count number of characters in a text file

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm currently trying to write a C program that utilizes multithreading with pthreads to count the number of occurences of characters in a text file, sent through a command line argument, using a 64kb buffer. I partition the file into 8 partitions for the 8 threads. I'm quite new to C and to multi-threading, so this is way over my head.

The program is counting the characters but not properly, and every time I run it I get different results. Here is my code (Updated)

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 

#define BUFFER_SIZE 65536
#define NUMBER_OF_THREADS 8 
#define NUM_CHARS 127


int charCount[NUM_CHARS + 1][8]; 

void* countChar(void *arg); 

struct bufferPartition {
    unsigned char* start; 
    int size;
    int index;  
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    pthread_t tid[NUMBER_OF_THREADS]; 
    pthread_attr_t attr[NUMBER_OF_THREADS]; 
    size_t fileSize;
    unsigned char* buffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(BUFFER_SIZE); 
    unsigned int bufferPartitionSize;

    printf("%i", argc); 
    if(argc != 2){
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: a.out <integer value>\n");
        return -1; 
    }

    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "r+");

    if(fp == NULL){
        printf("Error! Could not open the file.");
        return -1; 
    }
    fileSize = fread(buffer, 1, BUFFER_SIZE,fp); 

    fclose(fp);

    if(fileSize % 8 != 0){
        bufferPartitionSize = ((8 - (fileSize % 8)) + fileSize) / 8;
    }else{
        bufferPartitionSize = fileSize / 8;
    }

    for(int index = 0; index < NUMBER_OF_THREADS; index++){

        struct bufferPartition* bufferPartition = (struct bufferPartition*)malloc(sizeof(struct bufferPartition)); 

        bufferPartition -> size = bufferPartitionSize;
        bufferPartition -> start = buffer + (index * (bufferPartition -> size));
        bufferPartition -> index = index + 1; 

        pthread_attr_init(&attr[index]);
        pthread_create(&tid[index], &attr[index], countChar, bufferPartition);
    }

    for(int index = 0; index <= NUMBER_OF_THREADS; index++){
        pthread_join(tid[index], NULL); 
    }

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= 128; i++){

        for(unsigned int k = 1; k <= NUMBER_OF_THREADS; k++){
            charCount[i][0] += charCount[i][k]; 
        }
        if(i < 32){
            printf("%i occurrences of 0x%x\n", charCount[i][0], i);
        }else{
            printf("%i occurrences of %c\n",charCount[i][0], i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
} 

void* countChar(void *arg){

    struct bufferPartition* bufferPartition = (struct bufferPartition*) arg; 
    unsigned int character;
    int threadNumber = bufferPartition->index;

    for(int index = 0; index < bufferPartition -> size; index++){

        character = bufferPartition -> start[index];
        (charCount[character][threadNumber])++; 
    }   
}
```

Comment: You can get undefined behavior with your code. The range of a character is likely either `0` to `255` if your system's default character is unsigned, or `-128` to `127` if your system's default character type is signed.  Both of those can be outside your code's acceptable range of `0` to `127`.  The easiest solution would be to use `unsigned char *` for your buffers, and `UCHAR_MAX + 1` for the number of elements in your `charCount` array:  `int charCount[UCHAR_MAX + 1][NUMBER_OF_THREADS];`  Indexing with a signed `int` could make things even worse if the conversion from char is sign extended.

Comment: Got it. I did that and the code is still counting characters that aren't in the file.

Comment: What are you getting for `file_size`?  Could you post your updated code?

Comment: Updated. The file_size is coming out to the correct character count in my file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have one single `bufferPartition` structure that you pass to all of the threads. That means they will all share that single one, and if you change the members of the single structure all the threads will use that.

You need to allocate one structure per thread.

Comment: Awesome, that was it! Thank you!